# Reallocation of Automatic Variables in a Worker Thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, memory-management

Am I right in thinking that, in the following snippet, the automatic variables `x` and `y` will be reallocated on the stack on every pass of the while loop and never released, eventually leading to stack overflow? Will there also be 10 reallocations of `z` on each pass, before they are released after exciting from the scope of the inner `while` loop?

If this snippet is placed in a worker thread, will the stack be saved for re-entry after the thread has served its time allocation, i.e., will `x` and `y` *never* be deallocated?

```
while (1)
{
    int x = 0;
    int *y = &x;

    while (x < 10)
    {
        int z = 0;
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no problem. The automatic variables can easily reuse the same space each time. Remember that the automatic variables' lifetimes end at the end of the block, so they never live longer than one iteration.

(In fact, you would need a lot *more* code to construct something where each iteration used a *different* memory location -- you'd have to keep an extra counter around and compute an offset each time!)

Comment: For `z`, I see your argument since the scope of the inner `while` loop is clear to me. But for the `while(1)`, won't `x` and `y` always be in scope and so never be cleaned-up?

Comment: @EdKing: I think you're misunderstanding what "the block" is. It's the thing delimited by the braces. The block is entered and exited in ever iteration.

Comment: @EdKing Disregard my earlier comment, I thought you were asking about `z`. For `x` and `y`, yes they are in scope while the function is running, *but* why would there be a need to reposition them on every iteration of the while loop? They just stay there and are cleaned up when the function exits.

Answer (score 1):

> eventually leading to stack overflow?

No.  Automatic variables are cleaned up when they go out of scope.  If you like, you could think of the stack growing at the beginning of every iteration, and then shrinking at the end of every iteration.  (Whether or not it happens like this in practice is a different matter...)

> If this snippet is placed in a worker thread, will the stack be saved for re-entry after the thread has served its time allocation, i.e., will x and y never be deallocated?

In a functioning system, each thread gets its own stack, which is cleaned up when that thread terminates.

Answer (score 1):

The space for `x`, `y` and `z` will be reused in every loop round. There's no dynamic allocation or deallocation anywhere.

Usually the space for local automatic variables will be allocated on the stack at function entry and will be released when the function ends.

Answer (score 1):

For situations such as this, you can easily check what the compiler is doing by using

`gcc -g -c yourfile.c`

and then looking at the generated assembly with

`objdump -d -M intel -S yourfile.o` :

```
00000000 <main>:
int main() {
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
```

Ah! This is where the stack pointer is modified. Notice that it's left alone for the rest of the your function: the stack doesn't grow.

```
    while (1)
        {
            int x = 0;
   6:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
```

Let's put `x` at `[ebp-0xc]`...

```
            int *y = &x;
   d:   8d 45 f4                lea    eax,[ebp-0xc]
  10:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],eax
```

...and `y` at `[ebp-0x8]`.

```
            while (x < 10)
  13:   eb 10                   jmp    25 <main+0x25>
        {
                int z = 0;
  15:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
```

`z` is always at `[ebp-0x4]`!

```
                ++x;
  1c:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
  1f:   83 c0 01                add    eax,0x1
  22:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
  25:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
```

`x` still at `[ebp-0xc]`!

```
  28:   83 f8 09                cmp    eax,0x9
  2b:   7e e8                   jle    15 <main+0x15>
  2d:   eb d7                   jmp    6 <main+0x6>
```